# spring boot + gradle + reusable library compilation failed

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have very simple structure of project that uses Spring-boot. It is web application that uses some lib that uses jdbc.

So my root `setting.gradle` is following:

```
include ':app:myWeb', 'components:myBackend'
```

application's standalone `build.gradle` compiles reusable lib with:

```
...
compile(project(":components:myBackend"))    
...
```

But during compilation of myBackend I can get 2 types of errors:

1) no main class (but remember it is a lib), so I can fix it by turning off `apply plugin: 'spring-boot'`

2) Or error is following:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':components:myBackend:compile'
>   Could not resolve org.springframework:spring-jdbc:.  Required by:SBSServer.components:myBackend:unspecified

So my question is: how to create reusable library that uses spring-jdbc?
The text of myBackend build.gradle is there http://codepad.org/Xg3Kys73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead if removing the spring-boot plugin completely you probably just need to switch off the repackage task:

```
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}
```

Comment: Why is it not a solution? I don't really understand the requirement if that didn't work.

Comment: my pardon! After detailed review I've understood your idea!